# Failed to cache package shared libs when install apk

Tags: android, installation, unity-game-engine

I confront this error when made Unity3D plugin for Android.

```
08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123): Failed to cache package shared libs

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123): java.io.IOException: Couldn't create cached binary /data/data/com.alpaca.billing/lib/libunity.so in /data/data/com.alpaca.billing/lib

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.internal.content.NativeLibraryHelper.copyNativeBinaryLI(NativeLibraryHelper.java:289)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.internal.content.NativeLibraryHelper.copyNativeBinariesLI(NativeLibraryHelper.java:260)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:3474)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.replaceNonSystemPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:5834)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.replacePackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:5800)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:6136)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.access$2200(PackageManagerService.java:145)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at com.android.server.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:4820)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)

08-29 20:57:56.544: W/NativeHelper(123):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

My Unity3D is 3.5.5f3, and I tested it on two Android Phone :
1.Nexus S, Android 4.0. Everything is fine.
2.HTC Wildfire S, Android 2.3.3. The Unity3D Android plugin sample is OK, my plugin has this error.

I have searched the internet and found someone confronted this error but don't found the reason and solution. I have enough internal and sd space for installing this apk. Because I'm not sure which part caused this error, besides the Unity3d forum I also ask for help on stackoverflow, may this error lead by Android OS or the phone compatibility。

Anybody can tell me what caused this error and how to solve it? Thank you.